# Twillio WhatsApp Adapter Microsoft botframework

Tags: azure, twilio, botframework, chatbot, whatsapp

I cannot seem to find the problem with linking a microsoft bot to whatsapp via Twilio.

I have followed instructions to setup the Twilio WhatsApp adapter

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@botbuildercommunity/adapter-twilio-whatsapp. I have implemented this on the standard echo bot for testing(code is attached of the index file)

I am getting a bad request error in Twilio logs
See below

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you please provide more details on what is working and what isn't, what you have tried, and the error(s) specifics? There is very little that can be suggested based on the above. For reference, please see [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi Steven.thank you for your response.i have edited the question with some screenshots.Basically I am trying to integrate a microsoft bot to whatsapp via twilio using the whatsapp twilio adapter. I have followed the steps in the botbuilder community. But I am still getting an error on twilio. Don't know what I am missing.

Comment: @TameezMoosa `Bad Gateway` looks like an error on the side of your endpoint. Could you have a look at your server logs? Could it be that not all dependencies are installed in the right way?

Comment: @TameezMoosa any news regarding this?

Comment: Still have this issue.